# How to check whether nested scroll view is scrollable or not after rendering the list/items in UI without user action in android?

Tags: android

I m using recycler view with nested scroll view on top, but recycler view i have nested scroll enabled as false in xml &  i m dependent on nested scroll view for scrolling.Now i need to check on rendering items on ui i can check whether the view is scrollable or not pragmatically in android?

How to check whether recycler view is scrollable or not after rendering the list/items in UI without user action in android?

How to check view is scrollable or not without any user action on rendering the items in UI in android?

I m stuck on this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tried  below condition cardList.canScrollVertically(1) || cardList.canScrollVertically(-1) always getting false even though list can scrolled.This is not working

Comment: i see it will Returns:
true if this view can be scrolled in the specified direction, false otherwise.but always getting false

Comment: Check the size of the populated list in recycler / list view if the list is greater than 10 or more then it is scrollable otherwise not

Comment: it depends on screen height also for checking it is scrollable or not, we cannot fix one limit as 10?

Answer (score -1):

You can check is view is scrolling or not by using below code

```
mNestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged()
            {
                // you can do whatever you want on scroll changed here.
                
                
                // And if you want to know whether view is at the bottom, then use below code
                View view = mNestedScrollView.getChildAt(mNestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
                int diff = (view.getBottom() - (mNestedScrollView.getHeight() + mNestedScrollView
                        .getScrollY()));
                if (diff == 0) {
                    // Scrolled to bottom of the view.
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can we check whether we can scroll when rendering list in ui?